# Splitting a Rectangle into 2 halves and getting the dimenions of the top halve.

Tags: geometry

Hey im making a game and i need to get the dimensions of the top half of a rectangle.

Say i had a rectangle with the height of 15 and the width of 10.

Firstly how would i split it into 2 sections, top and bottom.

Secondly, how would i get the dimensions for the top.

[image: Platform]

Comment: Could you add an image of what you are trying to calculate, because now, the answer I would give is just $\frac {15}2$ or $\frac{10}2=5$, depending on the orientation.

Comment: ye sure il add it in now.  Basically i have a platform and i want to set a value when the player lands on the top and no other part of the rectangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the sections have to be the same, you have two options: 2 rectangles of 15x5 or 2 rectangles of 7.5x10. In any case, you just have to divide the length by 2.

Comment: so if i had a rectangle with the length of 128 id divide by 2.  And if the part i want is greater than 64 is that the top half ?

Comment: If you divide the height by two, you will have an upper and lower rectangle. If instead you divide the width by two, you will have a left and right rectangle. 
I guess you are in the first case, and yes, the part you want will have values greater than half the value of the height.